# Bluetooth stream receiving suggestion

Tags: java, bluetooth

i developed application in j2se my data coming from Bluetooth my laptop and GPS both are connected via Bluetooth. GPS send me stream which received by my laptop but i don't know how to this stream come in my jese application. i can show this stream through similar application . sorry for my poor english.

thanking you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [javax.comm.SerialPort](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/index.html) class

Unfortunately, I lost the link to the library itself.